# APACHE POI getting exact font color from excel in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

In excel sheet how to get the exact Font color value using Apache POI in java. I tried to get font color by using

org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font f = book.getFontAt(style.getFontIndex());
short clrIdx = f.getColor();

but it is not giving the exact color index. After getting this color value i have to apply the same color in the PDFtable. Here, I am doing the excel to pdf conversion by reading each excel cell format and creating the same using pdf in iText.

Please help me!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try looking up the details of the colour with that index in the spreadsheet palette?

Comment: I want to get exact color of the text and I need to convert that color to the iText Pdf basecolor....

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the RGB values from the Excel font color.  You can get those values in a couple of steps.

To get the appropriate POI `Color` object, you need to go down the HSSF or XSSF path, extract the appropriate HSSFColor or XSSFColor, then get the RGB values out of the color.

```
int red = 0;
int green = 0;
int blue = 0;
if (font instanceof HSSFont)
{
   HSSFColor color = ((HSSFFont) font).getHSSFColor(hssfWorkbook);
   // 0: red, 1: green, 2: blue
   short[] rgb = color.getTriplet();
   red = rgb[0];
   green = rgb[1];
   blue = rgb[2];
}
else if (font instanceof XSSFFont)
{
   XSSFColor color = ((XSSFFont) font).getXSSFColor();
   byte[] rgb = color.getRgb();
   // Bytes are signed, so values of 128+ are negative!
   // 0: red, 1: green, 2: blue
   red = (rgb[0] < 0) ? (rgb[0] + 256) : rgb[0];
   green = (rgb[1] < 0) ? (rgb[1] + 256) : rgb[1];
   blue = (rgb[2] < 0) ? (rgb[2] + 256) : rgb[2];
}
// Use the rgb values here.
```

Then you can use the rgb values to create your `BaseColor` object in iText.

**Update:**

There are several Apache POI bugs filed related to extracting colors in XSSF (for .xlsx files):

[#51222](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51222)

[#51236](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51236)

[#52079](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52079)

[#53274](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53274)

These bugs show up when XSSF is dealing with theme colors.